# Websites for amateur scientists

Tags: physics

Are there any online sites where amateur scientists can post
ideas and results, including Latex equations, allowing discussion,
feedback, critiques etc.?
For years I’ve built up a moderately technical system of ideas,
quite possibly "Not even wrong", but seemingly connected with
the nexus between cosmology & black holes and slightly touching on
a core entropy equation in string theory.  It reproduces one
Planck probe result (age of the universe) and the M-sigma
relation between SMBHs and stellar velocities, for example.
I can’t really send this stuff to actual theorists, since I’m an
amateur and for all they know, I’m one of those cretin crackpots
out to disprove Einstein.  Of course, professional journals are
entirely out of the question.  Very frustrating.
Thanks for your time, Gene

Comment: What do you want from that site? Should experts read it? Should it be for all disciplines?

Comment: @user111388 Primary goal would be to amateurs share their ideas with each others and with experts.

Comment: @peterh: for sharing with each other, maybe reddit? I saw there is eg a "Collatz conjecture" subreddit (this is a famous math. conjecture for which a lot of laypersons claim to have a proof). But experrts will there be probably not.

Comment: @user111388 Reddit is an internet forum, I think some more serious would be useful. I am thinking on some latex/pdf sharing like a science journal.

Comment: @peterh: Are you the questioner? I really doubt a science journal like that exist - it would be flooded with shit immediately and nobody would read it.

Comment: @user111388 No, but I think this question is useful. Of course, some type of quality control should exist. Note, various scientists are also complaining about the flood of shit in the pro journals, and particularly that these mislead funding decisions.

Comment: @peterh: Sure - but an amatour journal would be 10000x times worse. There is a good motivation for reading pro journals - unfortunately not for such a journal.

Comment: @user111388 I think quality control could happen on a way that everybody can choose what he considers shit and what not. Then, you would see a point value calculated by the votes weighted by people voting similarly as you. On this way, collatz conjecture proovers would be happy on each other, and your votes would help you to find the quality content.